# Create a shell scrip from bat script

Tags: command-line, scripts, python

I am trying to make my python program compatible with linux and I honestly have no idea how write a shell script. I do know a bit of batch scripting since I got this to work.

```
@echo off

chcp 65001 > NUL
cd /d "%~dp0"

if exist %SYSTEMROOT%\py.exe (
   cmd /k C:\Windows\py.exe -3.5 -m pip install --upgrade -r  Requirements.txt
    exit
)

python --version > NUL 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto nopython

cmd /k python -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
goto end

:nopython
echo ERROR: Git has either not been installed or not been added to your PATH

:end
pause
```

Does anyone out there have time to help me get this to work as a shell script so it can be executed on linux?

Comment: Well, if you wrote this batch script, explain what it does.

Comment: Well ,python is cross platform pretty much, why not handle  it in the puthon code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
```

Since shell scripts don't echo commands by default, an equivalent is unnecessary.

---

```
if exist %SYSTEMROOT%\py.exe (
   cmd /k C:\Windows\py.exe -3.5 -m pip install --upgrade -r  Requirements.txt
    exit
)
```

The `py` launcher is not used on Linux systems. Instead, call `pip3`. The equivalent of the system-installed `pip3` (i.e., installed using the  package manager) would be `/usr/bin/pip3`:

```sh
if [ -x /usr/bin/pip3 ]
then
    /usr/bin/pip3 install --upgrade -r  Requirements.txt
    exit
fi
```

However, it might be better to use any available `pip3`:

```sh
if command -v pip3 > /dev/null
then
    pip3 install --upgrade -r  Requirements.txt
    exit
fi
```

`command -v` can be used to check if a program is in the `PATH` (and it prints the path to that program, which we discard using `> /dev/null`). You could also check for `python3` and run `python3 -m pip`.

---

```
python --version > NUL 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto nopython

cmd /k python -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
goto end

:nopython
echo ERROR: Git has either not been installed or not been added to your PATH

:end
pause
```

We don't have `goto` in shell scripts.

An equivalent would be something like:

```sh
python --version 2>&1 > /dev/null    # Note the order of redirections
if [ $? != 0 ]    # $? is like ERRORLEVEL
then
    echo ERROR: Git has either not been installed or not been added to your PATH
else
    python -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
fi
```

Which would be more readable, IMO, as:

```sh
if python --version 2>&1 > /dev/null
then
    python -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
else
    echo ERROR: Git has either not been installed or not been added to your PATH
fi
```

---

Side note: **Git** has not been installed? O.o

Comment: Ah thx, will see if I can get it to work =D